# Which of the following octahedral complexes absorbs the photon with the longest wavelength, λ?

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory, ligand-field-theory

I wonder which of the following absorbs photons with the longest wavelength, $\ce{[Cr(CN)6]^3-}$, $\ce{[Cr(SCN)6]^3-}$ and $\ce{[Cr(H2O)6]^3+}$.

I know the one to absorb the highest wavelength should also have the highest spin. Since all of these are coordination isomers, I think the strong-field ligands should have higher energies (making the answer $\ce{[Cr(CN)6]^3-}$).

I hope someone can clarify the relation between ligand field strength and energy. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Look up the spectrochemical series, although empirical this is good at predicting the d orbital splitting and so absorption band frequencies for metals in 'normal' oxidation states.

Answer (score 3):

Since CN- is a strong field /pi-acceptor ligand, therefore, it will create larger splitting. So for transition higher energy will be needed. It means that in case of Complexes with CN- higher energied photons i.e. photons with shorter wave length will be absorbed.